# Есть альтернатива использованию трёхмерного массива для хранения данных

Tags: c#, массивы

Уважаемые участники форума. Использую трёхмерный массив для хранения констант для расчёта с одинаковыми параметрами, но разного "класса", где каждому "слою" соответствует поле констант одного класса. Подскажите, есть ли альтернатива использованию трёхмерного массива для этих целей?

Comment: Ничего не понятно без примера, но думаю, что вам поможет:

1. Использование словаря
2. Объединение измерений в отдельные структуры или классы

Comment: Покажите какой-то пример ваших данных. Правильно структурировать данные не всегда просто. И речь о хранении в программе или хранении в файлах и т.д.? Если в программе, то ничего не мешает вам использовать классы нужной вам структуры.

Comment: Альтернатива всегда есть, вопрос - чему именно